# How to style multiple appended checkboxes with labels

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, label, styling

I'm trying to style my appended checkboxes. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you can do this by 'hiding' the checkboxes and styling the labels instead.

Finaly I got it working, but I have multiple checkboxes and not functioning for all the checkboxes. I need the counter variable for other functions, so I can't get rid of the counter, unless you have a better idea ofcourse.

Can you help me fixing the checkboxes so they:

- toggle the class of the input text field next to it ( working in the demo)
- but also toggle the css of the checkbox it self ( NOT working in the demo and need help with it)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
</div>
 <button id="appendbtn">append an answer</button>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #222222;
}
#container {
    background: #edece9;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#container div {
    height: 40px;
}
.green {
    color: green;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: #999;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #0080FF;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var counter = 0;

$("#container").append('<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<label for="checkbox' + (counter) + '">' + '</label>' + '<input value="mark this answer"  type="text" class="inputfield' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>' + '<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<label for="checkbox' + (counter) + '">' + '</label>' + '<input value="mark this answer"  type="text" class="inputfield' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>');

$("#appendbtn").click(function () {
    $('<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<label for="checkbox' + (counter) + '">' + '</label>' + '<input value="mark this answer"  type="text" class="inputfield' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>').appendTo('#container');
});

$("#container").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "change", function () {
    $(this).nextAll().toggleClass("green");
});

$(".item").click(function () {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("clipped");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/haEq9/)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew! Interesting question. Here's your answer:
You weren't increasing the counter hence it was working for just the one checkbox. I have also added the ability to add/remove the `class green` on on the checkbox itself.

Jquery Changes: **(Request you to increase the counter in whatever way suits you. I have just tried to mimic the functionality required of the checkboxes. handling the counter variable is totally upto you)**

```
var counter = 0;

$("#container").append('<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<label for="checkbox' + (counter) + '">' + '</label>' + '<input value="mark this answer"  type="text" class="inputfield' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>');

counter++;

$("#container").append('<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<label for="checkbox' + (counter) + '">' + '</label>' + '<input value="mark this answer"  type="text" class="inputfield' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>');

counter++;

$("#appendbtn").click(function () { $('<div>' + '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox' + (counter) + '" class="item"/>' + '<label for="checkbox' + (counter) + '">' + '</label>' + '<input value="mark this answer"  type="text" class="inputfield' + (counter) + '"/>' + '</div>').appendTo('#container');
                                   counter++;
});

$("#container").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "change", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
    $(this).nextAll().toggleClass("green");
});

$(".item").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggleClass("clipped");
```

});

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/haEq9/6/)

Comment: Wow, Aditya thank you so much! :) I'm happy I wasn't that far away from the solution. Great, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Always a good feeling when you're not very far from the solution. SO rocks!